# Search 2 times for match between 2 tables

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 tables with ID.

I want to do something like a left join:

I want that if the ID from TABLE1 is not exist in TABLE2, it will search for ID in TABLE2 with the same 5 digits.

But I want it to search a match between last 5 digits **just after** it didn't find a completed match.

For example:

Table1:

```
ID       Name
1111111  'aa'
2222222  'bb'
3333333  'cc'
4444444  'dd'
5555555  'ee'
6666666  'ff'
```

Table2:

```
ID       City
1166666  're'
7833333  'tv'
4444444  'gh'
8547555  'ie'
6666666  'rt'
```

The accepted Results:

```
ID       Name  City  Status
1166666  'aa'  're'  ok
2222222  'bb'        no_record
3333333  'cc'  'tv'  ok \\last 5 digits are match.
4444444  'dd'  'gh'  ok
5555555  'ee'        no_record \\ just the last 3 digits are match.
6666666  'ff'  'rt'  ok
```

In my example, if it will search together for a complete match **or** last 5 digits, he will match `6666666` to `1166666` and not to `6666666`.

How should I write this?

Comment: Join to table 2 twice once for ID once for last 5 on ID. and use coalesce to combine t2 and t3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Access, you can use the following if the last five characters are unique:

```
select t1.*, t2.city,
       iif(t2.id is not null, "ok", "no record)
from table1 as t1 left join
     table2 as t2
     on right(t2.id, 5) = right(t1.id, 5);
```

You can extend this for your purposes as:

```
select t1.*, nz(t2.city, t2_5.city) as city,
       iif(t2.id is not null or t2_5.id is not null, "ok", "no record)
from (table1 as t1 left join
      table2 as t2
      on t2.id = t1.id
     ) left join
     table2 as t2_5
     on right(t2.id, 5) = right(t1.id, 5) and t2.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the last 5 of a number with MOD so the query would look like this:

```
SELECT T1.NAME, COALESCE(T2.CITY, T3,CITY) AS CITY
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T3 ON MOD(T1.ID,100000) = MOD(T2.ID,100000)
```

Comment: Access requires parenthesis in multiple JOINs. The above code is not Access SQL.

Comment: @SunKnight0 -- everytime I've used it it will put those in automatically

Comment: Don't think coalesce works in Access.  I just looked that one up use NZ instead (But only if 2 objects being compared)  and `T3,City` s/b `T3.City`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/coalesce-function-access-custom-web-app

Answer (score 0):

Join to table 2 twice. once on full ID, once on right ID and coalesce.

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Name, Nz(T2.City,T3.City) as City
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
 on T1.ID = T2.ID
LEFT JOIN table2 T3
 on right(T1.ID,5) = right(T3.ID,5)
```

if access doesn't have coalesce use if or isnull or NZ

Comment: dunno; can't check.  but implicit casting should let it I would think.

Comment: It will not, but `CStr` can be used: `Right(CStr(T1.ID),5)`

Comment: hmm... so you this that an answer that cast numbers as a string, run a string function on it and then do a string compare.  As op. to an arithmetic function and compare?  The string functions should be 10 to 30 orders of magnitude slower?

Comment: Access requires parenthesis in multiple JOINs

Comment: @sunKnight0 No; Access just puts them in for it's own benefit.  To my knowledge they are only required when you mix inner/left/right/full outer joins but in a left left, it doesn't REQUIRE them.

Comment: @hogan you're right performance would be worse... but how do we know ID is numeric? :P

Comment: @xQbert: No, it throws an error if you try to do more than one JOIN without parenthesis.

Comment: I've never had that problem in cmd.execute(SQL). or is this going in though the GUI?  But then the last time I touched access was back in 1995...